# Fix Title wrap indent on Divi Accordion

Tags: accordion, divi

Noticed that titles wrap weird in Divi Accordion module on responsive phone portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Assumes titles are h4; adjust accordingly

```
.et_pb_toggle_title:before {
    left: 3px !important;
}

body h4.et_pb_toggle_title:before {
    margin-left: -43px !important;
}
body h4.et_pb_toggle_title {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```